Why does this command reduce the precision of the output? 11.4.2-MariaDB on Windows 10 Pro
I am using a library to create ulids, one of the functions allows extracting the timestamp used to create the ulid.  However it loses 1ms due doing the final conversion in a single step:
Expected timestamp value is 0.191, actual output is 0.190
select from_unixtime( conv('0193E1B6222F',16,10)/1000.0 ); -- .190
We can verify the precision is being messed up by checking the timestamp digits:
select from_unixtime( conv('0193E1B6222F',16,10)/1000.0 , '%f' ); -- Result: 190999
If we store the result of the division in a variable and pass it to the function, everything works as intended:
select from_unixtime( 1734658630.191, '%f' ); -- Result: 191000
My question is where/why does the calculation lose precision when conducted in the one step?
Platform is 11.4.2-MariaDB on Windows 10 Pro.
Library used is ulid_converter
